# Problem sending the type date with Angular

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

When I add the date to Spring from Angular, Spring save the day before instead the date that I insert.
When I tried on postman everything works so the problem is when Angular send the data.
My code on Spring model is:

```
  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        private LocalDate importDate;
        @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
        private LocalDate expireDate;
```

in my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/addProduct")
        public ResponseEntity<Response> saveProduct(@RequestBody @Valid Product product) throws BadRequestException {
            log.info("Product to String: " + product);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(Response.builder()
                    .timeStamp(now())
                    .data(Map.of("product", productService.addProduct(product)))
                    .message("product added")
                    .status(CREATED)
                    .statusCode(CREATED.value())
                    .build()
            );
        }
```

In my component.html:

```
 <p-calendar appendTo="body" id="importDate" [(ngModel)]="product.importDate" placeholder={{product.importDate}} dateFormat="yy-mm-dd"></p-calendar>

In my components ts:
this.service.saveData(this.product).subscribe({
        next: (v) => this.toastMessage(v.status,v.message),
      error: (e) => this.errorMessage(e.error.message),
      complete: ()=> this.service.getData().subscribe(data=>{this.products=data})
      });
```

I really can't figure out why, thanks a lot who gonna reply me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First correct the date to local timezone.
Append `'Z'` to `date` for getting the correct value with local timezone.

```
const localDate = date + 'Z';
const dateISO = new Date(localDate).toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are expecting date in iso string at backend which is not default when javascript converts date to string. you can use toISOString() method for this.

```
new Date().toISOString()
```

the above is just an example. toISOString can be called on any date object.

Comment: Would it be more about updating `this.product` to update properties `importDate` and/or `expireDate` to be ISO date strings? `new Date()` may not reflect the date of those objects values.

Comment: you can call toISOString on those date objects. the code here is just a sample.

Comment: Why not actually make the answer specific to their question and usage? Why just a an arbitrary sample? It could help them resolve their issue more effectively.

Comment: cuz the question doesn't give the data to deal with

Comment: Which Data do you need?

Comment: this.product because thats what you are sending to api.